# If elseif statement Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In column A I have target production, in column B I have actual production, and in column C I have the delta between the two. I simply want to loop through each row in column C and flag each value according to a strategic bucket. The sample code I tried before going into master document is below.

My issue is surrounding how to perform the action on the current cell in the loop. The code is just coloring the last cell I clicked on instead of the cell being evaluated. Any suggestions?

```
Sub StratBuckets()

Dim Delta As Variant
Dim n As Integer

n = 0           
For n = 0 To 15
    ' works up to this point --> points to the right value
    Delta = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:Z1000").Find("Start Date").Offset(n, 3).Value

    If Delta > 0 And Delta <= 10 Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow        
    ElseIf Delta > 10 Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen        
    ElseIf Delta < 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed                
    Else        
    End If               
Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `.Interior.Color` on the right cell.

If `Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:Z1000").Find("Start Date").Offset(n, 3)` is the cell you want to colorize, then do :

```
Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:Z1000").Find("Start Date").Offset(n, 3).Interior.Color = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go, is to Set a Range `DeltaRng` to the `Find` with:

`Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:Z1000").Find("Start Date")`,

then if the `Find` is successful, get the `Delta` value 3 column on the right with `Delta = DeltaRng.Offset(n, 3).Value`.

At last, when you are inside your `If Delta > 0 And Delta <= 10 Then` etc.. you can modify the `.Interior.Color` of the cell with `DeltaRng.Offset(n, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow`.

**Code**

```
Sub StratBuckets()

Dim DeltaRng As Range
Dim Delta As Variant
Dim n As Long

For n = 0 To 15
    ' works up to this point --> points to the right value
    Set DeltaRng = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:Z1000").Find("Start Date") '.Offset(n, 3).Value

    If Not DeltaRng Is Nothing Then '<--make sure Find was successful
        Delta = DeltaRng.Offset(n, 3).Value '<-- find the Delta value 3 columns to the right

        If Delta > 0 And Delta <= 10 Then
            DeltaRng.Offset(n, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        ElseIf Delta > 10 Then
            DeltaRng.Offset(n, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        ElseIf Delta < 0 Then
            DeltaRng.Offset(n, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If

Next n

End Sub
```